# How do I return a list of values instead of a string when querying a oracle database using XPath?

Tags: java, sql, xml, oracle, xpath

I am using XPath to query an oracle database where the field I am querying looks like:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<film>
    <title>Godfather, The</title>
    <year>1972</year>
    <directors>
        <director>Francis Ford Coppola</director>
    </directors>
    <genres>
        <genre>Crime</genre>
        <genre>Drama</genre>
    </genres>
    <plot>Son of a mafia boss takes over when his father is critically wounded in a mob hit.</plot>
    <cast>
        <performer>
            <actor>Marlon Brando</actor>
            <role>Don Vito Corleone</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>Al Pacino</actor>
            <role>Michael Corleone</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>Diane Keaton</actor>
            <role>Kay Adams Corleone</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>Robert Duvall</actor>
            <role>Tom Hagen</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>James Caan</actor>
            <role>Sonny Corleone</role>
        </performer>
    </cast>
</film>
```

I want to return the all the actors who have starred in the film the godfather. At the minute my code looks like:

```
result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a.FILM.extract('/film[title=\"Godfather, The\"]/cast/performer/actor/text()') "
                + "FROM ASS2_Film a "
                + "WHERE a.film.existsNode('/film[title=\"Godfather, The\"]')=1");

System.out.println("\nActor");            

while (result.next()) {   
    System.out.println(result.getString(1)+"\n");
}
```

At the minute my code is returning:

```
Actor
Marlon BrandoAl PacinoDiane KeatonRobert DuvallJames Caan
```

Where as I want it returned as:

```
Actor
Marlon Brando
Al Pacino
Diane Keaton
Robert Duvall
James Caan
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXTRACT` (and `EXTRACTVALUE`) are deprecated functions. You should use `XMLTABLE` instead:

```
with sample_data as (select xmltype('<film>
    <title>Godfather, The</title>
    <year>1972</year>
    <directors>
        <director>Francis Ford Coppola</director>
    </directors>
    <genres>
        <genre>Crime</genre>
        <genre>Drama</genre>
    </genres>
    <plot>Son of a mafia boss takes over when his father is critically wounded in a mob hit.</plot>
    <cast>
        <performer>
            <actor>Marlon Brando</actor>
            <role>Don Vito Corleone</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>Al Pacino</actor>
            <role>Michael Corleone</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>Diane Keaton</actor>
            <role>Kay Adams Corleone</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>Robert Duvall</actor>
            <role>Tom Hagen</role>
        </performer>
        <performer>
            <actor>James Caan</actor>
            <role>Sonny Corleone</role>
        </performer>
    </cast>
</film>') x from dual)
select x.*
from   sample_data sd,
       xmltable('/film[title="Godfather, The"]/cast/performer' passing sd.x
                columns actor varchar2(50) path '//actor',
                        role varchar2(50) path '//role') x;

ACTOR                                              ROLE                                              
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
Marlon Brando                                      Don Vito Corleone                                 
Al Pacino                                          Michael Corleone                                  
Diane Keaton                                       Kay Adams Corleone                                
Robert Duvall                                      Tom Hagen                                         
James Caan                                         Sonny Corleone
```

(I've included the role column just for additional info; you would just remove that column from the column list in the `XMLTABLE` part if you don't need to see it.)

Comment: You keep beating me to these *8-) The XPath might want to be `'/film[title="Godfather, The"]/cast/performer'` though? Or include the film title with a more complicated XPath, and filter it after the join.

Comment: and you keep finding flaws with my answers! *{;-) You're quite correct, of course, as per usual! *{:-D

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer and noting that EXTRACT (and EXTRACTVALUE) are deprecated. I didn't know that. Thanks