# ExtractValue from Oracle CLOB returning null

Tags: xml, oracle, extract, clob

I am new to XML and Clobs. I have read plenty of the posts concerning the subject. I am trying to extract the studentID value from this clob. I am using Oracle 11.2

```
<OcXml xmlns="http://oc.csr.com/xml">
  <OcSharedXml>
    <Templates>
      <Template ns:TemplateId="130" ns:TemplateName="Student Graduation Fees" ns:TemplateFilename="Student_Graduation_Fees_1.doc" ns:TemplateSequence="1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://oc.rsi.com/xml">
        <Sections>
          <Section ns:SectionId="146" ns:SectionName="Main" ns:SectionSequence="1" ns:MaxRepeat="1">
            <Elements>
              <Element ns:ElementId="134" ns:ElementName="CurrentDt" ns:FieldName="DateOfNotice" ns:DefaultValue="" ns:Editable="false" ns:ElementSequence="1" ns:ElementType="ElmProc" ns:Mandatory="false" ns:Shared="true" ns:DataType="String" ns:Format="NoFmt" ns:RecipientId="" ns:Multiline="false" ns:RecipientAddressFlag="false">
                <ElementValue>2/19/2015</ElementValue>
              </Element>
              <Element ns:ElementId="24" ns:ElementName="InvoiceNo" ns:FieldName="InvoiceNo" ns:DefaultValue="" ns:Editable="true" ns:ElementSequence="2" ns:ElementType="ElmProc" ns:Mandatory="false" ns:Shared="true" ns:DataType="String" ns:Format="NoFmt" ns:RecipientId="" ns:Multiline="false" ns:RecipientAddressFlag="false">
                <ElementValue>352</ElementValue>
              </Element>
              <Element ns:ElementId="16" ns:ElementName="StudentID" ns:FieldName="StudentID" ns:DefaultValue="" ns:Editable="true" ns:ElementSequence="3" ns:ElementType="ElmProc" ns:Mandatory="false" ns:Shared="true" ns:DataType="String" ns:Format="NoFmt" ns:RecipientId="" ns:Multiline="false" ns:RecipientAddressFlag="false">
                <ElementValue>557481300</ElementValue>
              </Element>
              <Element ns:ElementId="43" ns:ElementName="DegreeType" ns:FieldName="DegreeType" ns:DefaultValue="" ns:Editable="false" ns:ElementSequence="4" ns:ElementType="ElmProc" ns:Mandatory="false" ns:Shared="true" ns:DataType="String" ns:Format="NoFmt" ns:RecipientId="" ns:Multiline="false" ns:RecipientAddressFlag="false">
                <ElementValue>BS</ElementValue>
              </Element>
              <Element ns:ElementId="44" ns:ElementName="GraduationYear" ns:FieldName="GraduationYear" ns:DefaultValue="" ns:Editable="false" ns:ElementSequence="5" ns:ElementType="ElmProc" ns:Mandatory="false" ns:Shared="true" ns:DataType="String" ns:Format="NoFmt" ns:RecipientId="" ns:Multiline="false" ns:RecipientAddressFlag="false">
                <ElementValue>2015</ElementValue>
              </Element>
            </Elements>
          </Section>
        </Sections>
      </Template>
    </Templates>
  </OcSharedXml>
</OcXml>
```

This is my select statement. It returns nulls

SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(clob_column), '/Templates/Template/Sections/Elements/Element[@ElementName="StudentID"]') 
FROM student_table;

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't given all the nodes in the path - you are missing OcXml, OcSharedXml and Section, as well as ElementValue - but you also need to provide the namespace information since the attribute you're looking for is called `ns:ElementName`:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(clob_column),
  '/OcXml/OcSharedXml/Templates/Template/Sections/Section/Elements/Element[@ns:ElementName="StudentID"]/ElementValue',
  'xmlns="http://oc.csr.com/xml" xmlns:ns="http://oc.rsi.com/xml"')
FROM student_table;

EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(CLOB_COLUMN),'/OCXML/OCSHAREDXML/TEMPLATES/TEMPLATE/SECTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
557481300
```

Or simplifying/wildcarding the path:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(clob_column),
  '//Element[@ns:ElementName="StudentID"]/ElementValue',
  'xmlns="http://oc.csr.com/xml" xmlns:ns="http://oc.rsi.com/xml"')
FROM student_table;

EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(CLOB_COLUMN),'//ELEMENT[@NS:ELEMENTNAME="STUDENTID"]/ELEMEN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
557481300
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I appreciate your time and knowledge.

Comment: @Alex Poole Is there any reason why you didn't use XMLQUERY in your answer? Just curious as I didn't know EXTRACT(XML) and EXTRACTVALUE were deprecated until I read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29166579/55640
Have you started to move to XMLQUERY in your projects yet?

Comment: @IanCarpenter - I didn't have time to get it working; I was having trouble with the namespaces. I had intended to say to it was deprecated, and use an XMLQuery and/or XMLTable version, but forgot to add that. (Did you mean to link back to this answer?)

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thanks that helps, as I say I didn't realise that the EXTRACT functions were being replaced so I am getting myself up to speed with XMLQUERY via a blog post I am in the process of writing. Your answers here are always spot on so the use of EXTRACT made me start doubting myself. Apologies I meant to link to the answer of this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838219/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-values-instead-of-a-string-when-querying-a-oracle-data/28838353#28838353